# In this Javascript code, is `word` considered a function, variable, or object?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

I know that an object is a variable, and that a function is a type of object, but I'm still confused as to how your supposed to refer to `word` in the follow code:

```
var word;
exports.setWord = function(c, ch){
  word = c.get('chats')[ch];
  Ti.API.debug('Course ' + course.get('title') 
};

var updateView = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < word['comments'].length; i++){
    var text = word['comments'][i],  
};
```

Comment: JavaScript has dynamic types. So at the beginning, it's a variable of undefined, then within setWord it becomes an object.

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors. One missing parenthesis in line #4 and one missing brace in line #9.

Comment: Considering it's being accessed with `word['comments']`, that should tell you it's an object.

Comment: @Kolink except everything in _JavaScript_ is like an object, `(1)['constructor']['name'] // "Number"`, `(function(){})['constructor']['name'] // "Function"`, `('')['constructor']['name'] // "String"`

Answer (score 0):

"an object is a variable" isn't strictly true. A variable can *point* to an object, but the object itself isn't the variable. For example:

```
var a = new Foo();
var b = a;
```

Here you have two variables, but only one object. Now, often you will hear people say "a is an object" or "a is a Foo", but that's just a verbal/written shortcut for the more correct "a is a variable that currently points to an object of type Foo".

In your case, 'word' is always a variable. It starts out as a variable that isn't pointing to anything, or in other words it's undefined. Inside the setWord function, you assign an object to 'word' and so you could now say "word is an object", but more correctly you mean "word is a variable that currently points to an object".

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. In `var updateView = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < word['comments'].length; i++){
    var text = word['comments'][i],  
};`......does word is still an array or does it become an object that calls the `[comments]` array?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to word as "the variable word", but that's probably not what you're asking.

In line 1, all you know is that the variable named "word" is declared, but not defined.

In the `setWord` function, you're setting `word` to... something.  From that function on its own, we don't know what it's being set to, just that it's set.

`updateView` tells us more about what is expected of `word`.  `word['comments']` tells us that `word` is intended to be an object with a member named `comments`.  `word['comments']` is equivalent to `word.comments` - the only difference is the `[]` syntax lets you access the data member with a variable.  We can tell from what's done with `comments` that it's something that has a length.  While it's probably an array, we're not guaranteed that.

We're also not guaranteed that `word` means anything in the `updateView` function, because the code you provided doesn't show if `exports.setWord` is called before `updateView` is called.  If it's not, then `word` is still undefined, and `word['comments'].length` will throw an error.

Since all objects are dynamic, you never really know what will be inside an object.  You can just tell from the code what is expected of the object.  If you want to see every member inside the `word` object, you can do:

```
var s = "";
for (var member in word) {
    if (word.hasOwnProperty(member)) {
        s += member + ": " + word[member] + " [" + typeof(word[member]) + "]";
    }
}
alert(s);
```

This will go through each member in `word`, and if it belongs only to `word` print out its name, its value, and its type.  It may give you a better idea of what to expect from the `word` object.

Answer (score 0):

Word is a variable. No matter what's inside it, it will allways be a variable. Because Javascript is dynamic typed a variable may change the type of what it stores.

At the begining of the script word is ponting to the Undefined object and later it points to an object, but it is a variable.

**Edit fom coments:**

When you declare a new variable it is undefined until you assign something to it.

```
var word; //word is undefined
```

In the code there is an assignation to word

```
word=c.get('chats')[ch];//Now it has a primitive value or a pointer to an object
```

But can't know what is inside word now.

An object can be called in two diferent ways: obj['property'] or object.property.

```
word['comments'] //word is pointing an object
```

And here you are using the first one to invoke *word* , so we supose that the asignation of before was an object asignation.

And finaly you are calling the result of *word['comments']* as an array (or an object that has a length property and numeric index)

```
word['comments'].length
word['comments'][i]
```

Remember that in javascript all objects are assigned as references, so the variable will never be an object but a pointer to an object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where exactly does `word` point to an object?

Comment: `word = c.get('chats')[ch];` sets word to something, which is most likely an object or an instance of a constructor. I'll also mention that in _JavaScript_, an _Array_ **is** an _Object_.

Comment: And when you execute this `word['comments']` you are treating word as an object.